# How do I go about dividing in the LC-3?

Tags: lc3

Can some one please explain to me how to divide in the lc3. I'm really not understanding how to do it. For example, if i have the int 250 stored in a random memory location and it shows up as x0102 how do i do divide that to be able to break it apart so that 250 turns into 2, 5, 0?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, LC3 does not have a divide instruction, so you'll have to fake it using repeated subtraction.  So:

```
Number = 250
Divisor = 100
Result = 0
While number > divisor
  number = number - divisor
  result = result + 1
```

Now:

```
dividend = result
remainder = number
```

This can be repeated with the divisor decreasing in each iteration, which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.